# how to return the actual fraction value of two int numbers

Tags: c, casting

Is there any way by which we can get the answer for 1/2 as 0.5 where the data type of both the numerator and denominator are int in C.

Comment: No, you have to do a type cast.

Comment: There is, but it depends. Why are they `int`? are they literals? Where are you going to store the result? There are many things missing from your question.

Comment: yea that wont work, I have tried that already

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please put your question in context.

Comment: @9codie05 More experienced programmers are telling you what to do. It's a normal thing they do probably every day. Don't say it don't work because it does work, you just did it wrong.

Comment: yea.. I made a mistake.. it worked,, thanks

Comment: If I understand your question (which is a big if, and why it was closed) then sure: `int x = 10 / 2; printf("%d.%d\n", x / 10, x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expect a decimal value(which may not be the exact one), you'll have to cast it to a floating point type. For example:

```
int numerator = 1, denominator = 2;
printf("%g", (double) numerator / denominator);
```

Or, if exact values are called for, return a struct:

```
struct fraction
{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
};
```

and then

```
return (struct fraction){.numerator = 1, .denominator = 2};
```

Comment: thanks, there was a mistake in my code,, it worked :)

Comment: By "precious", do you mean "exact", with respect to floating-point innacuracy ?

Comment: @Quentin Yes. Answer edited.